# CiviCRM Multi-value Custom Data empty

Tags: import, multi-record

My civicrm version 4.6.2.
Drupal version 7.51.
I visited on this URL of the feature to test is /civicrm/import/custom?reset=1
This feature was not working correctly, such that if a custom field set was used for a specific Contact Type "individual".
Here is the screenshot of my custom data screen.

[image]

I can't see any custom field in dropdown box. It is fresh installation. How can I get custom data there?

My task is to check import system in civicrm. I have a csv file. I have to import data here through this section just this my task. But here custom data required and I can't see dropdown value here. but I have custom data I checked.

[image]

Comment: You mention it's a fresh installation - which wouldn't have multi-value custom data.  Can you show a screenshot of your relevant custom data screen?

Comment: @JonG Can you suggest me where I have to go in menu? I am new in civicrm.

Comment: In that case, it's very likely that the screen you're looking at is the wrong one - because the import screen you're looking at is for a very specialized form of data.  You would only be using this if you created an unusual type of custom field - which means you'd have visited the **Administer menu > Customize Data and Screens > Custom Fields** screen before.  If you update your question with more about what it is you're trying to do, we can probably help you better.  Also, please update the question with your CiviCRM version and your CMS?

Comment: @JonG Thanks for sharing. I just updated My question. Here I can see contact type "individual" has a custom data.

Comment: This doesn't show that it's "multi-value custom data".  In fact, since your screenshot shows the demo data, I can tell you there are no multi-value custom data fields in the demo set.  You can import your custom data using the normal import - **Contacts menu > Import Contacts**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer, you don't have any multi-value custom data, which is why the drop-down in question is empty.  To import custom data, please use the normal import screen, found at **Contacts menu > Import Contacts**.